# Are Java libraries shared in memory between processes?

Tags: java, libraries, jre

On Linux when two processes (programs) use the same native `.so` library it is loaded only once. The memory that contains the machine code is shared between processes as read-only so it doesn't have to be loaded twice.

But what about Java `.jar` libraries? Is the byte code loaded only once and shared between processes?

Maybe it depends on the JRE?

Answer (score 1):

Run `pmap [-x] <pid>` on the process to see what files it has memory-mapped.

I think it is unlikely that Java libraries inside a `.jar` *could* be shared, as a .jar is a **compressed** Zip archive – the code within cannot be directly executed by the JRE as-is, it has to be uncompressed first, so there is no point in sharing the archive if the decompressed data has to be stored elsewhere anyway.

(What allows .so objects to be automatically shared is them being *read-only mappings* that are directly backed by files, which is not the case for the decompressed bytecode that needs to be generated on the fly. The .so sharing that you mentioned is possible because programs *do not* simply open each .so and read it into memory; they [*map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) the file into memory, and the OS recognizes it as a "shareable" mapping.)

Other runtimes may have a form of caching, e.g. the .NET Framework runtime has Ngen (Native Image Generator) that pre-compiles the CLR bytecode into native files that could be directly mapped later, but I have not heard of Java JREs having such features.

Comment: What do you mean by decompressed bytecode is not read-only?

Comment: It didn't *originate* as a read-only mapping directly backed by some file (as is the case for .so's); it was generated "on the fly" by the JRE while decompressing. Even if it's marked as read-only later, there's nothing telling the kernel that this memory range in this process is identical to another range in another process, and there's also no mechanism that would avoid the need for each JRE to actually decompress the data in the first place.

Comment: Other runtimes may have a form of caching, e.g. the original .NET Framework runtime has Ngen (Native Image Generator) that pre-compiles the CLR bytecode into native files that could be directly mapped later, but I have not heard of Java JREs having such features.

Comment: But couldn't the JRE do memory sharing by itself using mmap?

Comment: In theory it could, although that's more complex as it needs to coordinate between all the JREs manually; it'd probably need to manage its own file-based bytecode cache in a central location. I've seen some language runtimes do it (I *think* Python does this with .pyc files?), haven't seen Java do it.